# PHP JSON with UTF8 characters

Tags: php, json

I'm sending a `JSON` message using this `PHP`:

```
$result = mysql_query("select a.id, ad.nombre, a.imagen, a.lat, a.long, ad.desc, a.url, a.email, a.tel, a.direccion, a.cp, a.poblacion, a.provincia from `bck_alrededor` a, `bck_alrededor_description` ad, `bck_alrededor_partner` ap
where a.id = ad.id_alrededor
and a.id = ap.id_alrededor
and a.id_cat = '$cat'
and ad.language = '$idioma'
and ap.id_partner = '$idp'",$link);

    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
    {   
        $id = $row['id'];
        $nombre = $row['nombre'];
        $imagen=$row['imagen'];
        $lat=$row['lat'];
        $long=$row['long'];
        $desc=$row['desc'];
        $url=$row['url'];
        $email=$row['email'];
        $tel=$row['tel'];
        $direccion=$row['direccion'];
        $cp=$row['cp'];
        $poblacion=$row['poblacion'];
        $provincia=$row['provincia'];

        if ($imagen <>'')
        {
            $imagen = $dir.'/'.$imagen;
        }

        $posts[] = array('nid'=> $id , 'title'=> $nombre, 'image'=> $imagen ,  'latitude'=> $lat, 'longitude'=> $long, 'html'=> $desc, 'web'=> $url, 'email'=> $email, 'phone'=> $tel, 'address'=> $direccion, 'cp'=> $cp, 'poblacion'=> $poblacion, 'provincia'=> $provincia );

    }
    $response['nodes'] = $posts;

    $current_charset = 'ISO-8859-15';
    array_walk_recursive($response,function(&$value) use ($current_charset){
         $value = iconv('UTF-8//TRANSLIT',$current_charset,$value);

    });

    echo json_encode($response);

    if(!headers_sent()) header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8', true,200);
    header('Content-type: application/json');
```

But I've got this JSON message with UTF8 escaped characters:

```
{"nodes":[{"nid":"87","title":"Tienda Oficial","image":"\/tiendaoficialgbc.png","latitude":"43.3021","longitude":"-1.9721","html":"Entra y adquiere todos los productos oficiales del GBC. En 48h los tienes en casa","web":"http:\/\/www.gipuzkoabasket.com\/tienda\/tienda_es.php","email":"gipuzkoabasket@gipuzkoabasket.com.","phone":"943 44 44 28","address":"Paseo de Anoeta 22, 1a Planta","cp":"20014","poblacion":"Donostia - San Sebasti\u00e1n","provincia":"Gipuzkoa"},{"nid":"88","title":"Tienda Oficial Salaberria","image":"\/tiendaoficialgbc.png","latitude":"43.30384","longitude":"-1.9797","html":"Entra y adquiere todos los productos oficiales del GBC. En 48h los tienes en casa","web":"http:\/\/www.gipuzkoabasket.com\/tienda\/tienda_es.php","email":"gipuzkoabasket@gipuzkoabasket.com.","phone":"943 44 44 28","address":"Jos\u00e9 Maria Salaberria 88","cp":"20014","poblacion":"Donostia - San Sebasti\u00e1n","provincia":""}]}
```

I've tried to use echo json_encode(utf8_encode($response)); but then I got a null JSON message in the client app.

How can I get a regular `JSON` message without `UTF8` characters?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\u00e1` is a perfectly valid way to escape Unicode characters in JSON. It's part of the JSON spec. To decode that to UTF-8, just `json_decode` it. `utf8_decode` has nothing to do with it.

What I don't understand is this code:

```
iconv('UTF-8//TRANSLIT',$current_charset,$value);
```

This says you're trying to convert from `UTF-8//TRANSLIT` to ISO-8859-15, which doesn't make much sense. The `//TRANSLIT` should come after `ISO-8859-15`, or you shouldn't be doing this conversion at all.

Comment: Thanks for your indications. It's very strange but my client app JSON parser is giving invalid json message and I can't access address value.